# Community Hide Built in Component from Guest User

Tags: community, lightning-aura-components, napili

I am wondering if it is possible to conditionally show or hide a built in lightning component on a communities page. We are using the napili theme.

One idea I had was to create a custom component, and then put the built in component inside of that component with a user access check, but I have no idea how to include a built in community component into my own component.  I feel like this should be possible, but I don't know how to access it, I don't see any components in the developer console which correspond to the napili components.

Comment: I am still wondering if this is possible.  Mainly how do I include napili components in my own components.  I was able to do a page variation in this case based on profile to hide the component from a certain class of users, but that might not always be an option.